# Looking for information on North Korean government/party/military organization late 1980s-early 2000s

Tags: north-korea

I'm working on a translation (not Korean) related to North Korea under Kim Jong-Il. Although it's mostly related to personal experiences, it does introduce leading figures in the state.  I need to use accurate titles and the best I can find online are contemporary positions.  My concern is that they don't appear to line up with what I'm seeing from the 90's so I assume the organization has been shaken up under Kim Jong-Un.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? (online resources, academic papers, books, etc.)

Comment: You might do better by focusing on the particular individuals that you want information about. Otherwise you might get answers that are too general to be of use.

Comment: Recommend you revise to ask a clear question in the title. I'm not sure what you want (other than "information")  Are you asking for the titles of NK paramilitary organizations? Or the titles of leaders of paramilitary organizations?  More precise questions get more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You will find very accurate information about NK positions at [WorldstatesMen](https://www.worldstatesmen.org/Korea_North.htm) website. However, I see the info there is quite basic, it may not include positions you're looking for.